# .net can't get datatable to update DB for a checkbox matrix

Tags: .net, sql-server, winforms

I am using MS Visual Studio 2013 to create an Employee Training Program for a client but cannot seem to figure one thing out...

The problem I have is writing any changes from a checkbox matrix back to the relevant table (VehicleTrainingMatrix)

Matrix summary: A vehicle manufacture has a range of vehicles and 3 departments of the build, Parts, Construction & Finishing. before the Matrix is displayed an Employee has been chosen in the program. Bascially each vehicle has a row showing the vehicle name then 3 checkboxes (1 per department) and if that Employee has been trained for a particular department for a particular vehicle you enter a Tick in the relevant place. Simple so I thought!?!?

The datatable was dragged from Data Sources onto the form.

It is based on the following SQL ...

```
    SELECT V.Vehicle, VTM.PART AS Parts, VTM.CONST as Construction, VTM.FIN AS Finishing
FROM VehicleTrainingMatrix AS VTM RIGHT OUTER JOIN
 Vehicles AS V ON VTM.VehicleID = V.ID AND VTM.EmployeeID = @IDparam
ORDER BY V.Vehicle
```

In my program I have the following line to load data:

```
Me.VehicleTrainingMatrixTableAdapter.FillByID(TrainingDBDataSet.VehicleTrainingMatrix, SelectedEmployeeID)
```

You should see the IDparam in the query is satisfied by the supplied SelectedEmployeeID variable.

VehicleTrainingMatrix table definition:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VehicleTrainingMatrix](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[VehicleID] [int] NOT NULL,
[PART] [bit] NULL,
[CONST] [bit] NULL,
[FIN] [bit] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([ID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Basically any row with a Tick in the matrix relates to one row in the table. The row will have the relevant Employees ID and Vehicle ID stored with a "1" (tick) in the relevant field PART, CONST or FIN (or a combination, 1 row could have all 3 of these ticked).

Loading of data works. The problem I have is writing back to the DB any Vehicle Training Matrix changes to the VTM table.

I have tried ticking "Generate Insert, Update and Delete Statements" in Advanced Options of the Table Adapter definition, but this does not happen. When you go back into the definition they are greyed out again. I have looked into this and I believe (correct me if I am wrong) it is because I have more than 1 table listed in my select query.
Another point is I do not really think I need the VehicleTrainingMatrix.ID field, I only added it when trying to get around this cannot write back to DB issue (I have been trying to sort this for a couple of days now) where one post seemed to indicate I needed a Primary Key to do it.

I have manually added the following into SQL

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[VehicleTrainingMatrix]
       ([EmployeeID]
       ,[VehicleID]
       ,[PART]
       ,[CONST]
       ,[FIN])
 VALUES
       (621, 2, 1, NULL ,NULL)
```

621 = Employee ID,

2 = The Vehicles ID value

1 = That employee is trained in the Parts Department for Vehicle with ID 2

NULL = That employee is NOT trained in the Construction Department for Vehicle with ID 2

NULL = That employee is NOT trained in the Construction Department for Vehicle with ID 2

Hopefully the above has all the details required but to summarize The Datatable reads from the DB and populates the Matrix perfectly. My problem is how can I get any changes to the Matrix (new ticks only I will be disabling the ability to untick, not quite sure how yet though). A change could involve having to create a new row in Table VehicleTrainingMatrix if an unticked row has a tick put in it or just updating an existing row.

So you know my level I am just getting back into programming (after quite a few years just doing support) and have basically taught myself .net (please dont respond with C examples) and VS 2014. I have had a huge learning curve but was doing really well up to this problem. Certain terminology may be lost on me so I would appreciate explantions rather than possible a short to the point answer.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to help.

Paul.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about the root cause of the problem. The fact that your select query is complex (has joins) is the reason Visual Studio cannot generate the Insert/Update/Delete statements for you automatically.

What you need to do then, is provide those queries.

You can right-click on the data source and open the properties view (if it's not already open on the right side of the screen usually).Then, in the properties, find the `InsertCommand`, `DeleteCommand`, and `UpdateCommand` properties. Click the little `...` button to edit those.

The `UpdateCommand` might look something like this:

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[VehicleTrainingMatrix]
    SET [PART] = @Parts 
      , [CONST] = @Construction
      , [FIN] = @Finishing
 WHERE [EmployeeID] = @EmployeeId
   AND [VehicleID] = @VehicleID
```

Make sure not to supply a value or the parameters. Leave the `ParameterSource` set to `none`. That way the data control you're using will automatically set the parameters.

The parameter names used in the query must be the same as the name of the DataKeyNames value in the GridView, DetailsView, or FormView.

Have a look at:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updatecommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Mike, firstly let me thank you for reply, it is much appreciated.

Thank you for confirming what the actual reason for my issue was (a quey contaning joins). Anyway, I created the UpdateCommand (Properties of my TableAdapter) first of all just how you typed it... But I received errors. In trying to fix these I added the EmployeeID & VehicleID columns to my query (I will hide them on the form) as they are also referenced as parameters so thought they must need to be selected (feel free to correct me if I am mistaken). This did not fix the errors. Continued...

Comment: When I run Me.TrainingTableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.TrainingDBDataSet) I get the error An unhandled exception... Additional information: The parameterized query '(@Parts bit,@Construction bit,... ...' expects the parameter '@Parts', which was not supplied.
Just to clarify in relation to your note about not supplying a value for parameters... When I 1st created the update command Visual Studio automatically created a Collection of Parameters. The above error was with these params in place. So I tried changing Parameters from Collection to None but still get a similar error just a shorter ...

Comment: I googled this and found I may need alter the params in the update query from e.g. @Parts to '%@Parts%' (inc the quotes). This just changes the error to: Additional information: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%@EmployeeID%' to data type int.
I have double checked and EmployeeID has a data type of Int in every table it is used so I don't understand that one.

Summary: I am sure we are on the right track but just missing something. If you (or anyone else, I'm not choosy) can help complete this you will make my week.
Thanks again,
Paul.

Comment: Hey Paul - sorry for the delay. Is this for a Windows Forms application or a Web Forms application?

Comment: Hello Mike, Just thought I'd check before going to bed. Dont apologise for delay I am grateful for your help. It is a Windows Form / MS SQL Server exe written in VB.net using VS Express 2013.
Two things I would like to check on:
1. In the properties of the TA's UpdateCommand - should I leave the auto generated parameters (they do seem to be correct to a novice) OR should I remove them?
2. In the Code should I be suppliying the params somehow to the update command. Currently the Matrix table is listed in the UpdateAll(Me.TrainingDBDataSet) command. So i dont believe i need a separate update? :}

Comment: So, looking over the comments and question one more time, in light of the updates, here's a few things: - the idea of adding the EmployeeID and VehicleID to the SELECT query was a good one. - the field names in the SELECT query much match the parameter names in the UPDATE query for auto-generated "plumbing" to work - technically, you'd want to use the autogenerated parameters and have the adapter + view take care of supplying the params and their values (will add some more..)

Comment: by the way - are you using a datagridview to display the matrix data?

Comment: Hi, Yes I dragged the DataSource setting it to DataGridView onto my form.
Beneath the form I have VehicleTrainingMatrixBindingSource & VehicleTrainingMatrixTableAdapter listed. The TA has 1 SQL part called FillByID (@IDparam) which is how the Matrix rows are filtered for the selected Employee.
also I would just like to clarify should I be using the '%paramname%' formatting or just paramname in my update statements.
I really do appreciate you helping me.
Pity I dont get an email informing me of your updates until 24 hours after you made the update:-( 
(My website has a contact details)Paul.

Comment: Mike, I have just got past the above errors by removing the Alias's in the update and select statements. Note: not using '%'s. So using AS's caused it. I will rename table columns to get around this. I now have other errors... A concurrancy error when updating but it has worked once. I have to give up for the weekend now though.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I am the poster of this question and thought I would update you as to what happened incase anyone else has a similar issue.

Firstly because my select statement that created the "Matrix" DataGridView had joins in it Visual Studio was unable to automatically generate the Insert, Update and Delete Statements.

My Select statement:

```
SELECT        V.Vehicle, VTM.Parts, VTM.Construction, VTM.Finishing, VTM.EmployeeID, V.ID AS VehicleID
FROM            VehicleTrainingMatrix AS VTM RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     Vehicles AS V ON VTM.VehicleID = V.ID AND VTM.EmployeeID = @IDparam
ORDER BY V.Vehicle
```

@IDparam is the Selected Employee's ID and is used via:

```
Me.VehicleTrainingMatrixTableAdapter.FillByID(TrainingDBDataSet.VehicleTrainingMatrix, SelectedEmployeeID)
```

I manually added the following statements:
Insert Statement:

```
INSERT INTO VehicleTrainingMatrix
                     (EmployeeID, VehicleID, Parts, Construction, Finishing)
VALUES        (@EmployeeID,@VehicleID,@Parts,@Construction,@Finishing)
```

Update Statement:

```
UPDATE       VehicleTrainingMatrix
SET                EmployeeID = @EmployeeID, VehicleID = @VehicleID, Parts = @Parts, Construction = @Construction, Finishing = @Finishing
WHERE        (VehicleID = @VehicleID) AND (EmployeeID = @EmployeeID)
```

At this point updates via the DGV on the form worked for existing rows I had manually entered but caused the error: --- Additional information: Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of 1 --- Whenever a change was made to a row that was not brought from the VehicleTrainingMatrix Table. Whatever I tried including setting the tables Primary Key to EmployeeID, VehicleID (the 2 columns used in the where clauses) I could not get around this error.
The Matrix created by the Select statement had the correct data on screen but it could only cope with changes to existing rows. i.e. I tick another department (Parts etc) of a row that already has a tick (and as long as that is the only change I made) everything is OK. However If I tick a row that currently has no ticks (but has been created by the Select with Joins) the Concurrency error occurs. After spending too much time trying to get Visual Studio to work as I wanted it to I decided to do a workaround which works a treat!
Before I Fill my Table Adapter from the DB I run the following SQL command:

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO VehicleTrainingMatrix (EmployeeID, VehicleID, Parts, Construction, Finishing) " & _
                                "SELECT " & SelectedEmployeeID & ", V.ID, NULL, NULL, NULL " & _
                                "FROM Vehicles V WHERE NOT EXISTS " & _
                                    "(SELECT VehicleID FROM VehicleTrainingMatrix VTM WHERE VTM.EmployeeID = " & SelectedEmployeeID & " AND VTM.VehicleID = V.ID)"
```

Basically this creates all rows the Matrix required in the DB before the Fill gets hold of them. This now allows any change to any row.

One thing I did try before the Insert Where statement above that failed was... I know the EmployeeID field in the created Matrix would be blank for any vehicle rows that had no VehicleTrainingMatrix record I programmically populated the TableAdapter rows with the EmployeeID so All fields had a value. This made no difference.

Note:  The parameters VS created from my SQL statements - I just left them alone. i.e. I dod NOT delete them.

I hope this helps someone out there.
Paul.